# Object from LINQ with a custom List

Tags: c#, linq

I'm expounding on this question: [Create object from LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526576/create-object-from-linq/19526666#19526666)

I've had to change the contactsList from a List to a List which will contain the Name and Id.

```
public class DataItem
{
    public String Location { get; set; }
    public List<ContactInfo> ContactsList { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    public String PersonName { get; set; }
    public Int32 PersonId { get; set; }
}

        var myData= from table in sqlResults.AsEnumerable()
                        group table by table["LOCATION"] into groupby
                        select new DataItem
                        {
                            Location = groupby.Key.ToString(),
                            ContactsList = groupby.Select(row => new ContactInfo 
                            {
                                PersonName =   row["PERSON"].ToString(), 
                                PersonId = (Int32)row["PERSONID"]
                            }).ToList()
                        }; 
//TreeView
tv.DataContext = BrokerData;
```

I'm getting a **Specified Cast is Invalid**

What am I doing incorrectly here?

**UPDATE**

I'm getting an highlighted error here:

```
new ContactInfo 
{
    PersonName =   row["PERSON"].ToString(), 
    PerrsonId = (Int32)row["PERSONID"]
}).
```

Comment: Well we don't even see `ContactTypeContactId` in your class example.

Comment: My guess is that row["PERSONID"] isn't an `Int32`, but a `long`.

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown?  At that location, what is the actual value of the object being cast, and what is it being cast to?  Odds are at that point you'll need to cast it to what it really is and then *convert* it, rather than casting it, to what you need it to be.

Comment: row["PERSONID"] could be null also

Comment: @Servy - It is being thrown when I try to view myData.  What will I need to convert?

Comment: What type is `sqlResults`? A `DataTable`?

Comment: @McGarnagle - It should be an Int32 - What do I need to do to fix it or to validate it.?

Comment: @PhilVallone - if it is null, what should I do?  Make PersonId nullable?

Comment: If indeed it is a `long`, then you would need to cast twice:  `(int)((long)row["PERSONID"])`.

Comment: @DStanley - var sqlResults = A method that returns a DataView

Comment: @webdad3 What should _you_ do if PERSONID is null?  Skip the record? If the answer is store `null` then yes, make `PersonId` nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the weakly typed indexer

```
PersonId = (Int32)row["PERSONID"]
```

use the strongly-typed `Field` extension method

```
PersonId = row.Field<Int32>("PERSONID")
```

If `PERSONID` can be null and you want to store `null` in that case, make PersonId nullable:

```
public Int32? PersonId { get; set; }
```

and

```
PersonId = row.Field<Int32?>("PERSONID")
```